# unable to persist data on postback in dotnetnuke7

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, checklistbox

I have my website running on dotnetnuke 7.4, i have a checklistbox which i bind on the page load, and after selecting items from it, user clicks on the submit button, the selected items should save in database, however when i click on the submit button, checklistbox gets blank, i tried to enable ViewState at :

1. Web.config level
2. Page Level
3. Control Level

But all in vain, it still unbinds checklistbox because of which everything disappears, i tried the same in plain .net and it works like a charm.

Is there any specific settings in dotnetnuke to support viewstate, or is there any other better option to achieve this.

Here's my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Entities objEntities = new Entities();
            List<Entities> obj = objEntities.GetList(2);
            chkBox.DataSource = obj;
            chkBox.DataTextField = "Name";
            chkBox.DataValueField = "ID";
            chkBox.DataBind();
        }

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in chkBox.Items)
            Response.Write(item.Text + "<br />");
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code here.

Comment: I have updated my question with code.

Answer (score -1):

There's the issue. Remove that `(!IsPostBack)` check in your `page_load` event. Have your code to be like below. Else, only at first page load you are binding the datasource to control which gets lost in postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Entities objEntities = new Entities();
            List<Entities> obj = objEntities.GetList(2);
            chkBox.DataSource = obj;
            chkBox.DataTextField = "Name";
            chkBox.DataValueField = "ID";
            chkBox.DataBind();
    }
```

OR, to be more efficient; refactor your code to a method like below and store the data object in `Session` variable like

```
private void GetDataSource()
{
  List<Entities> obj = null;

 if(Session["data"] != null)
 {
   obj = Session["data"] as List<Entities>;
 }
else
{
  Entities objEntities = new Entities();
  obj = objEntities.GetList(2);
}
  chkBox.DataSource = obj;
  chkBox.DataTextField = "Name";
  chkBox.DataValueField = "ID";
  chkBox.DataBind();
  Session["data"] = obj;
}
```

Call the method in your `Page_Load` event like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       GetDataSource();  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the prompt reply:
1. i have already enabled ViewState at the control and Page level, so why the session is required, i am able to maintain the viewstate in plain .net, then why not in dotnetnuke, does dotnetnuke handles viewstate differently.
2. if i keep the databinding without IsPostback with session, i will get the data binded on button click, but what about my selected values, it will get overrided by the next databound and i will always get all un-selected items.

Comment: @Abbas, not sure about  .net nuke but you will have to rebind the control on every postback / pageload; else the control will lost the datasource since it's a databound control. You will have to do separate stuff to retain the previous selection though.

Comment: I don't think i have to really rebind on every page load, asp.net handles it via viewstate, i even did it in plain .net, but that's not working in dotnetnuke, thats where i am stuck.